# Notation for two entangled registers

Tags: entanglement, terminology-and-notation

Suppose I have two registers x and y, of length m and n bits respectively. I want to initialize my system to contain an equal superposition of all $2^{n+m}$ states, then apply an oracle function (in superposition). How do I notate this correctly?

For example:

Consider the system $|\psi\rangle=|x_{m-1}\rangle...|x_0\rangle|y_{n-1}\rangle...|y_0\rangle = |x\rangle|y\rangle$

and quantum oracle $F(x,y)\rightarrow \{0,1\}$

1. Initialize the system to $|\psi_0\rangle=|0\rangle|0\rangle$
2. Apply the Hadamard gate to obtain uniform superposition over all states

   $|s\rangle$ = $H|\psi_0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n+m}}}\sum_{x=0}^{2^m}\sum_{y=0}^{2^n}|x\rangle|y\rangle$
3. Compute $|\phi\rangle = F(|s\rangle) = \alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle$, for $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{C}$

I hope the algorithmic steps I'm describing are relatively clear but is this the correct way to notate it?

Comment: How is your question related to your title?

Comment: A more general answer to the question, *why can't the state of the extra qubit be written in the form α|0⟩+β|1⟩* can be found in Chapter 10 of Rieffel & Polack, [Quantum Computing - a gentle introduction](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608150244118.pdf) (link to pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your notation is OK up to and including step 2, except for the range of summation. You need
$$
|s\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n+m}}}\sum_{x=0}^{2^n-1}\sum_{y=0}^{2^m-1}|x\rangle|y\rangle
$$
Now the problem is how to write down the effect of the oracle, and you cannot just write down the output qubit. I think you probably know this from the title of the question, because entanglement will appear that you're not describing. So, you have an oracle that acts as
$$
|x\rangle|y\rangle|0\rangle\xrightarrow{\text{oracle}}|x\rangle|y\rangle|F(x,y)\rangle.
$$
Hence, if the input is some superposition state such as $|s\rangle$, we have
$$
|s\rangle|0\rangle\xrightarrow{\text{oracle}}|\Psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n+m}}}\sum_{x=0}^{2^n-1}\sum_{y=0}^{2^m-1}|x\rangle|y\rangle|F(x,y)\rangle.
$$
You absolutely cannot describe (except in very special cases of $F$) the last qubit in the form $\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle$ because it is entangled with the other registers.

---

The question seems to be evolving into

> If I'm not measuring $x$ or $y$, why can't the state of the extra qubit be written in the form $\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle$?

There are several ways that this might be answered. Normally, I'd take the partial trace and calculate the reduced density matrix, but I infer from comments that the OP doesn't know this technique. Thus, let us try another route.

Let us assume that the extra qubit can be written in the form $|\psi\rangle=\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle$. This means that we could define a measurement
$$
P_\psi=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|\qquad P_{\perp}=|\psi^\perp\rangle\langle\psi^\perp|
$$
where $|\psi^\perp\rangle=\beta^{\star}|0\rangle-\alpha^\star|1\rangle$ is orthogonal to $|\psi\rangle$. If we can guarantee that the extra qubit is in that state, then we are guaranteed to get the measurement result $P_{\psi}$. In other words,
$$
\langle\Psi|\mathbf{I}\otimes\mathbf{I}\otimes P_{\psi}|\Psi\rangle=1.
$$
(The identity operations are how we say that we're not measuring the $x$ and $y$ systems.) I claim that there are no satisfying $\alpha,\beta$ where $|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1$, unless $F(x,y)$ is a constant function.

So, we start to evaluate
\begin{align*}
\langle\Psi|\mathbf{I}\otimes\mathbf{I}\otimes P_{\psi}|\Psi\rangle&=\frac{1}{2^{n+m}}\sum_x\sum_y\langle F(x,y)|P_{\psi}|F(x,y)\rangle \\
&=\frac{1}{2^{n+m}}\left(\sum_{x,y:F(x,y)=0}|\alpha|^2+\sum_{x,y:F(x,y)=1}|\beta|^2\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2^{n+m}}(M|\alpha|^2+(2^{n+m}-M)(1-|\alpha|^2))
\end{align*}
Where $M$ is the number of values such that $F(x,y)=0$. Setting this equal to 1, we can rearrange for $|\alpha|^2$:
$$
|\alpha|^2=\frac{M}{2M-2^{n+m}}
$$
For $|\alpha|^2$ to be a valid value, it must be $0\leq|\alpha|^2\leq 1$. One has to be careful in the analysis here. If we assume that $2M>2^{n+m}$, then the denominator is positive, and $|\alpha|^2\leq 1$ implies
$$
M\geq 2^{n+m}.
$$
This only happens if $M=2^{n+m}$, in other words, $F(x,y)=0$ for all $x$ and $y$. On the other hand, if $2M<2^{n+m}$, the denominator is negative, and so $|\alpha|^2\geq 0$ implies $M\leq 0$. This can only happen if $M=0$, i.e. all answers $F(x,y)$ give answer 1.

We conclude that unless $F(x,y)$ is constant, there is no valid $\alpha,\beta$ so that the measurement gives probability 1, which means there is no pure state description of that qubit.

Comment: Thank you, this is useful. Suppose I do not care about, and do not measure the state of $|x\rangle|y\rangle$ after applying F: can I then revert to $\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle$ for my description of the oracle output? i.e. there is a certain probability to measure each that I will estimate via Brassard mean estimation?

Comment: No, you cannot revert to $\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle$. If you want to describe only the state of the extra qubit, then you have to trace out the other registers, and that will return a mixed state description. Think about it another way: is there a projective measurement that you can do on that single qubit that gives an answer with probability 1? (No.)

Comment: That said, if you start your extra qubit in one of the states $(|0\rangle\pm|1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$, it will always come out on the state that you put it in as.

Comment: Not sure I understand your first comment. (1) What does it mean to "trace out the other registers"? (2) any measurement on that qbit will give sometimes 1 and sometimes 0 (for nontrivial F) so I think I'm missing why your second question is relevant? (3) whether or not I can use the $\alpha,\beta$ notation is there any reason I can't estimate the proportion of 1s and 0s I will measure on that bit using Brassard's algorithm (obviously re-running F as needed)?

Comment: (3) I'm useless at names of things, so I don't know what "Brassard's algorithm" specifically is, but you certainly could just measure the qubit in the 0/1 basis and repeat to estimate the probability of getting 1, which gives the fraction of values $F(x,y)$ for which $F(x,y)=1$.

Comment: Brassard actually had a couple of algorithms which as I understand it estimate the mean state more efficiently than simple repeated sampling. They derive from amplitude estimation which underlies Shaw/Grover. Most recent is here https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.4267

Comment: But, that may be another question altogether! In the context of this one, if I'm not measuring $|x\rangle|y\rangle$ then I'm still unclear why I can't just sum all the amplitudes for $|1\rangle$ and $|0\rangle$ into $\alpha, \beta$? And then sample it (whether by repeated measurement or Brassard doesn't matter in this context)

Comment: The updated answer still loses me. "If we can guarantee that the extra qubit is in that state, then we are guaranteed to get the measurement result Pψ". I thought Pψ was an operator not a result? with form [[$\alpha^2$,$\alpha\beta$][$\alpha\beta$,$\beta^2$]]? hence the line below that does not evaluate to 1

Comment: Happy to go learn more elsewhere if you can point me at the right resource to understand this

Comment: Measurements are described by measurement operators, each operator corresponding to a different outcome, so the operators are as convenient as any other method to refer to the outcomes.

Comment: I thought outcomes were eigenvectors of measurement operators (each of which had multiple possible outcomes)?

Comment: A measurement observable is an alternative way of describing measurements where the different edge values correspond to different outcomes. But the eigenspace for each eigenvalue is specified by a projector (what i’ve referred to as the measurement operator), matching up to what i’ve been describing.

Comment: To aim for an intuitive explanation of the above, I came up with this: *interference only takes place if an identical pure state can be reached by multiple paths. thus, whether or not the system will exhibit interference in |F(x,y)> depends on the superposed states of |x> and |y>, irrespective of whether or not we measure them. A description which discards |x>|y> therefore cannot fully describe the system's behaviour.* Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that would do.